# Set imageView as a banner inside an app

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I wonder if Apple Review team allows such thing.
Imagine you have a imageView inside your app, and you set it as a static banner, without any clicking option etc.

Do you think Apple will allow sth like this?

To give you a better notion of what I mean:

[image]

The banner with "Amlozek" text is just a completely static ImageView that can have no interaction with user.

Do you think Apple would say "hey, you are placing ads inside your app omitting the official way to do that" or they just don't care about such small banners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple don't restrict ads in apps to iAd. You're permitted to use other ad platforms. Therefore, there would be no reason for Apple to reject your app.

Comment: Yeah sure, but this is not using any ad platform, it's just am ImageView :) So, apple has nothing to do with that, right?:)

Comment: @DCDC Apple don't read your code, they use the app from an end-user point of view. They don't know the image doesn't change—it just looks like an ad. Either way, it makes no difference.

Comment: Alright, so the conclusion is that I have nothing to worry about, right? Cool, thank you